# Lucene in java method not found

Tags: java, lucene

I am using those code below for searching but some methods shows error;

```
FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDirectoryPath));
  writer = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, 
     new StandardAnalyzer(),true,
     IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

In this code open and MaxFieldLength shows error. I am using lucene 6.0.0.

The open() method shows the error

> The method open(Path) in the type FSDirectory is not applicable for
>   the arguments (File)

and MaxFieldLength shows:

> MaxFieldLength cannot be resolved or is not a field

I used the code provided here:

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_first_application.htm
```

Comment: You can check the javadoc for different versions of Lucene and figure out the issue I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the code is written against an older version of lucene.
Newer versions have switched form the old java io to the java nio.
So you would use something like this:`FSDirectory.open(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("yourPath", "index")`

In version 6.0 the IndexWriter hasn't got a member called `MaxFieldLength` Please see [Lucene IndexWriter API](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/index.html).

More help can be found in the  [migration guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/MIGRATE.html)

You may wan't to look up older versions of the migration guides as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation of the [FSDirectory.open][1] method in the Lucene documentation you will find that it except Path argument. You can Paths.get(URI) method to get Paths from the URI. Paths are part of the Java 7.