# Unable to identify error in Lucene MoreLikeThis

Tags: java, lucene, morelikethis

I need to use Lucene MoreLikeThis to find similar documents given a paragraph of text. I am new to Lucene and followed the code [here](https://github.com/martin-magakian/Lucene-MoreLikeThis-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/doduck/luceneMoreLikeThis/Main.java)

I have already indexed the documents at the directory - "C:\Users\lucene_index_files\v2"

I am using "They are computer engineers and they like to develop their own tools. The program in languages like Java, CPP." as the document to which I want to find similar documents.

```
 public class LuceneSearcher2 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    LuceneSearcher2 m = new LuceneSearcher2();
    System.out.println("1");
    m.start();
    System.out.println("2");
    //m.writerEntries();
    m.findSilimar("They are computer engineers and they like to develop their own tools. The program in languages like Java, CPP.");
    System.out.println("3");
}




private Directory indexDir;
private StandardAnalyzer analyzer;
private IndexWriterConfig config;

public void start() throws IOException{
    //analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42);
    //config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_42, analyzer);
    analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

    indexDir = new RAMDirectory(); //don't write on disk
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542551/lucene-in-java-method-not-found?rq=1
    indexDir = FSDirectory.open(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\Users\\lucene_index_files\\v2")); //write on disk
    //System.out.println(indexDir);
}
private void findSilimar(String searchForSimilar) throws IOException {
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);
    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    System.out.println("2a");
    MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(reader);
    mlt.setMinTermFreq(0);
    mlt.setMinDocFreq(0);
    mlt.setFieldNames(new String[]{"title", "content"});
    mlt.setAnalyzer(analyzer);
    System.out.println("2b");



    StringReader sReader = new StringReader(searchForSimilar);

    //Query query = mlt.like(sReader, null);
    //Throws error - The method like(String, Reader...) in the type MoreLikeThis is not applicable for the arguments (StringReader, null)

    Query query = mlt.like("computer");
    System.out.println("2c");
    System.out.println(query.toString());

    TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query,10);

    for ( ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs ) {
        Document aSimilar = indexSearcher.doc( scoreDoc.doc );
        String similarTitle = aSimilar.get("title");
        String similarContent = aSimilar.get("content");

        System.out.println("====similar finded====");
        System.out.println("title: "+ similarTitle);
        System.out.println("content: "+ similarContent);
    }
    System.out.println("2d");

}}
```

I am unsure as to what is causing the system to not generate an output/

Answer (score 0):

What is your output ? I am assuming your not finding similar documents. The reason could be that the query you are creating is empty.

First of all to run your code in a meaningful way this line

```
Query query = mlt.like(sReader, null);
```

needs a String[] of field names as the argument, so it should work like this

```
Query query = mlt.like(sReader, new String[]{"title", "content"});
```

Now, in order to use MoreLikeThis in Lucene, your stored Fields have to have the set the option to store term vectors "setStoreTermVectors(true);" true when creating fields, for instance like this:

```
FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
fieldType.setStored(true);
fieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);
fieldType.setTokenized(true);
Field contentField = new Field("contents", this.getBlurb(), fieldType);
doc.add(contentField);
```

Leaving this out could result in an empty query string and consequently no results for the query